# ROS Answers SE migration: ROSJOY Node

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm using Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04.

I have been using ROS for a few months, but have very little programming knowledge. I was asked to write a node to control a servo using a joystick (and Arduino). The most experience I have in this s controlling an AR Drone with a ps3 controller. I have looked at the [Writing a Teleop node tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ps3joy/Tutorials/WritingTeleopNode), but that’s it. I get what the script is doing, but that is not the same as knowing how to do it myself. Does anyone know of a good source to learn how to write such a node, preferably in python. Or, are there any scripts for controlling a servo with rosjoy?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191735/rosjoy-node/) by [dshimano](https://answers.ros.org/users/19862/dshimano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 129 on 2014-09-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are lots of good places on the internet to learn python. I know a few people that like the codeacademy course: http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/python

The [ROS tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) are a good place to get started working with ROS.

The [rospy publisher and subscriber tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29) goes through the basics of writing a simple publisher and subscriber in python.

The biggest trick to learning programming is that you have to practice a lot. Start with something close to what you want, and try to modify it to suit your purposes. Test early and often. There's usually a fair amount of failing in there as well.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0